# Can I use gsap, parallax.js in angular7

Tags: angular7, gsap, parallax.js

I'm new to angular Im planning to create a website with parallax.js and gsap tweenmax effects with angular7. I want to know where do I get some reference regarding with this

Answer (score 1):

Angular works with most JavaScript libraries. An example on parallax.js in particular can be found [here](https://medium.com/@jonmichaeldreher/how-to-use-parallax-js-in-angular-2-5-2-10-c06e95cb7f1). The post uses parallax.js with angular 5, on angular 7 the angular-cli.json was renamed and remodelled to angular.json but the rest should be the same. For tweenmax, a tutorial can be found [here](https://medium.com/@mr.frag85/using-gsap-with-angular-6-project-it-works-on-prod-too-9ac036f21487).

You will notice, the process to include a third party library is always the same or pretty similiar:

- Install the library through npm
- Include the library either through the angular.json script section or through import in your project (depends on the packaging)